# Is there an "event log" on Wine?

Tags: logging, wine, event-log

When an app running under Wine logs something to the Windows event log, what does Wine do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows stores the event [logs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315417) in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog`. I opened up the wine regedit and tried to go to that location but there does not appear to be an Eventlog key under the Services key for wine.

I would expect that all error messages that would usually go to the event log would be passed to standard output. In order to see what errors occur during the execution of your program, open up a terminal and type `wine applicationName` and it will open up your windows program and any errors will appear in the terminal.

Comment: I just peeked into the source code of Wine, and can confirm that all it does is do a standard Wine trace message.  If the right WINEDEBUG is defined, it output to stderr.  This doesn't help w/ postmortem if the end user wasn't already setup for caputing output!  I added some code in my application to dump my events out to a text file as well.

Comment: Nice! I'm working on learning programming so I can do what you just did.